# Dask One Hot Encoder handle_unknown="ignore", work around?

Tags: dask, dask-ml

I understand this it not handled right now but it's preventing me from being able to encode features in a real time fashion (like in a live API service) against a trained OneHotEncoder / Pipeline.

How do people work around needing to encode data in real time if there happens to be a need to encode things that haven't been seen before?

Thanks